# Ionic 3 with icon inside ion input at the right side using grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a **login form** that has an **email** and **password** `input`. What I want to do is a **little eye outline icon** on the right side of the input. That has a function that will **show and hide** the `password`.

The function is fully working however. I can't get the design that I want to. Something like [this](https://prnt.sc/gz12xg). But in my case I am not using a `<ion-item>`

Here is my code in my **html**

```
    <ion-row class="p-l-4">
          <ion-col col-12 class="col-static">
            <ion-input class="input-cover" type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" required></ion-input>
<!-- Small button icon of eye goes here -->
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
```

I tried to do anything with it but ended up messing it. Because my input has a border.

Here is the image below of the result.

[image]

Here is my code of my input in **scss**

```
ion-input {
  border: 5px !important;
}

.text-input-ios, .text-input-md {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.text-input {
    margin: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 8px);
    padding: 13px 8px;
}
```

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For those who land here I tried adding the icon inside a button it worked. 
My code:

```
<ion-item id="location">
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="searchLocation" type="text" placeholder="Enter / Select Location" (ionChange)=segmentChanged($event)></ion-input>
  <button class="find-me" clear item-right icon-only>
    <ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-item>
```

Here is the link [Right align a button inside an ion-input](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/right-align-a-button-inside-an-ion-input/50398)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-icon name='eye' item-right></ion-icon>
   <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

If you are using Grid, try this..

```
<ion-grid>
   <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-md-10>
         <ion-input type="email" id="login_email" name="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email" required></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-md-2>
         <ion-icon name='eye'></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: I tried it but the eye icon is outside of the input field.

Comment: You can add border to ion-row instead of text-input. Give custom class name to ion-row and add border styles to that.

Answer (score 2):

```html
 <ion-row class="p-l-4">
    <ion-col col-12 class="col-static">
       <ion-input class="input-cover" type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" required></ion-input>
<ion-icon name='eye' class="eye-icon" item-right></ion-icon>
        </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
```

```
.col-static{
  position:relative;
}

.col-static .eye-icon {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:10px;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Tried that but the icon is out of the input field. It is showing below or out of the col

Comment: can you attached the screenshot please